# How to know which activity loaded the html page?

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

i have an html page which allows to edit some information, there are two activites loading this page

```
1)InsertInfo.java
2)EditInfo.java
```

there are different JS functions for both of these functionality, how can i differ that which activity has loaded the page so if `InsertInfo` loads the page i use insertion functions and when `EditInfo` loads page i use Edition functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not pass a parameter in your request to this webpage?
For example, from `InsertInfo` you open url http://example.com/edittext?activity=InsertInfo,
and from your `EditInfo` class you open http://example.com/edittext?activity=EditInfo.